# How can I add more than one value in a table cell?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I currently have a material table as follows:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="blogPosts">

  <!-- Title Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Title</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.title }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Author Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="author">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Author</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.author }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Country Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="country">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Country</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.country }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Link Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="link">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Links</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"><a href="{{element.link}}"><i class="material-icons">link</i></a></td>
  </ng-container>



  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

This displays just one link under the Links header, but what do I need to do in order to display multiple values say:

1. Display a list of links using a *ngFor
2. Display something like (not within a *ngFor):

```html
  <ng-container matColumnDef="link">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Links</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"><a href="{{element.linkToWiki}}"><i class="material-icons">link</i></a></td>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"><a href="{{element.linkToAmazon}}"><i class="material-icons">link</i></a></td>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: Why not add them in the same cell?

Comment: adding them in the same cell with a new td does not seem to work ( like the one shown in the last snippet )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="link">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Links</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <a href="{{element.linkToWiki}}"><i class="material-icons">Wiki link</i></a>
        <a href="{{element.linkToAmazon}}"><i class="material-icons">Amazon link</i></a>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

You shouldn't nest `<td>` directly within, they should with decent immediately within `<tr>`. If you want each links to have they own `<td>` then you should check on [`colspan`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp)